# Home surveillance with Dropbox integration

Tags: python, dropbox, motion-detection

I'm trying to make a home surveillance system with Dropbox integration. The code is taken from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/01/home-surveillance-and-motion-detection-with-the-raspberry-pi-python-and-opencv/

I have tried a lot but the vodeo is not being uploaded to Dropbox. I think its the problem with what I have entered dropbox_base_path in conf. json file.
I actually don't know how to enter the path there. Please help me.
This is the code.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import argparse
import warnings
import datetime
import dropbox
import imutils
import json
import time
import cv2
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c", "--conf", required=True,
    help="path to the JSON configuration file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# filter warnings, load the configuration and initialize the Dropbox
# client
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
conf = json.load(open(args["conf"]))
client = None
if conf["use_dropbox"]:
    # connect to dropbox and start the session authorization process
    client = dropbox.Dropbox(conf["dropbox_access_token"])
    print("[SUCCESS] dropbox account linked")
# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = tuple(conf["resolution"])
camera.framerate = conf["fps"]
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=tuple(conf["resolution"]))
# allow the camera to warmup, then initialize the average frame, last
# uploaded timestamp, and frame motion counter
print("[INFO] warming up...")
time.sleep(conf["camera_warmup_time"])
avg = None
lastUploaded = datetime.datetime.now()
motionCounter = 0
# capture frames from the camera
for f in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image and initialize
    # the timestamp and occupied/unoccupied text
    frame = f.array
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    text = "Unoccupied"
    # resize the frame, convert it to grayscale, and blur it
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    # if the average frame is None, initialize it
    if avg is None:
        print("[INFO] starting background model...")
        avg = gray.copy().astype("float")
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        continue
    # accumulate the weighted average between the current frame and
    # previous frames, then compute the difference between the current
    # frame and running average
    cv2.accumulateWeighted(gray, avg, 0.5)
    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(gray, cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg))
    # threshold the delta image, dilate the thresholded image to fill
    # in holes, then find contours on thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, conf["delta_thresh"], 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # if the contour is too small, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < conf["min_area"]:
            continue
        # compute the bounding box for the contour, draw it on the frame,
        # and update the text
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = "Occupied"
    # draw the text and timestamp on the frame
    ts = timestamp.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p")
    cv2.putText(frame, "Room Status: {}".format(text), (10, 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, ts, (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    # check to see if the room is occupied
    if text == "Occupied":
        # check to see if enough time has passed between uploads
        if (timestamp - lastUploaded).seconds >= conf["min_upload_seconds"]:
            # increment the motion counter
            motionCounter += 1
            # check to see if the number of frames with consistent motion is
            # high enough
            if motionCounter >= conf["min_motion_frames"]:
                # check to see if dropbox sohuld be used
                if conf["use_dropbox"]:
                    # write the image to temporary file
                    t = TempImage()
                    cv2.imwrite(t.path, frame)
                    # upload the image to Dropbox and cleanup the tempory image
                    print("[UPLOAD] {}".format(ts))
                    path = "/{base_path}/{timestamp}.jpg".format(
                        base_path=conf["dropbox_base_path"], timestamp=ts)
                    client.files_upload(open(t.path, "rb").read(), path)
                    t.cleanup()
                # update the last uploaded timestamp and reset the motion
                # counter
                lastUploaded = timestamp
                motionCounter = 0
    # otherwise, the room is not occupied
    else:
        motionCounter = 0
    if conf["show_video"]:
        # display the security feed
        cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        # if the `q` key is pressed, break from the lop
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

The below is the conf.json file.

```
{
    "show_video": true,
    "use_dropbox": true,
    "dropbox_access_token": "my access token",
    "dropbox_base_path": "motion",
    "min_upload_seconds": 3.0,
    "min_motion_frames": 8,
    "camera_warmup_time": 2.5,
    "delta_thresh": 10,
    "resolution": [640, 480],
    "fps": 16,
    "min_area": 5000
}
```

I have also tried
/motion as dropbox_base_path
No error is shown but the video is not being uploaded.
Here is temimage.py

```
import uuid
import os
class TempImage:
    def __init__(self, basePath="./", ext=".jpg"):
        # construct the file path
        self.path = "{base_path}/{rand}{ext}".format(base_path=basePath,
            rand=str(uuid.uuid4()), ext=ext)
    def cleanup(self):
        # remove the file
        os.remove(self.path)
```

Comment: If you could share your code/current path and the error message you receive, I think it'd be quite useful for those who can help you with your problem.

Comment: @bkaankuguoglu  , I have added the code now.